# Create login token (cookie)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am programming a login-token working like this:
As soon as you log in with the right username and password the server will respond with a token. This token consists of an identifier and a token and will be saved locally.

When a server request is done, the whole login token is sent back to the server. It checks if the identifier is valid. If the identifier is valid, the token will be checked. Depending on this it will either give permission and send back a login token with the same identifier but a new token or if it is invalid, the user will be logged out and the identifier+token will be removed from the database.

So, all in all, it is used to have a permanent login for users but the code should be thief-proof.
This system worked well so far. But there is a problem. If the user has slow internet and does several requests at once (e.g. refreshing page a few times) the user will be logged out because he used an old token but the server already created a new one.

So my question is: Is there a good way to avoid that? I thought about saving more than one token and delete them as soon as the user used a newer one. But this would result in a higher risk and some functionalities would lose its effects.

Comment: Why don't you just use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Prevention) - `[...] change the value of the cookie with each and every request [...] can cause other technical problems (for example [...] two legitimate, closely timed requests from the same client can lead to a token check error on the server [...]` This is not exactly a new problem.